# When can TPM_Start(ST_Clear) be issued to a TPM?

Tags: tpm

TPM 1.2 has an NVRAM permission attribute called `TPM_NV_PER_WRITE_STCLEAR`. The TPM 1.2 specification describes it as

> The value is writable until a write to the specified index with a datasize of 0 is successful. The lock of this attribute is reset by TPM_Startup(ST_CLEAR). Lock held for each area in bWriteSTClear.

Is `TPM_Start(ST_CLEAR)` something that only works once per power cycle?